# Assembly of the neighbor project of the same solution does not come to bin folder

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dll, build, .net-assembly

#### Visual Studio 2017, Net Framework 4.6.2

I have a solution consisting of 2 projects

1. Project A (type DLL) depends of third party assembly X.dll that depending on Y.dll
2. Project B (type EXE WinForms) depends of project A

When I start to build a solution then A.dll and X.dll get to the bin\Debug folder of the project B,
but Y.dll does not get there, although Y.dll is present in the bin\Debug of the project A.

How to make copying Y.dll to the bin\Debug folder of the project B happen automatically?

Comment: I'm guessing that project A has a reference to Y.dll, which makes it automatically copy into A's bin\Debug. You could reference Y.dll from project B to achieve the desired effect, but that would be quite ugly assuming you do not directly use code from Y.dll in project B. A better approach is to go to the properties of project B and define a post-build event to copy all required dlls that are not directly referenced to the required runtime locaiton:
Project B properties -> Build Events -> add a batch command in the post-build event box to copy Y.dll

Comment: JonyVol Thank you